# How can I delete tests in Nunit when I loaded the Project From Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit, nunit-console

I am attempting to automate tests using Nunit and have loaded a project from Visual Studio. I do not understand how to delete Tests i do not want in my project. I know I can choose not to run tests but when i am automating the tests I will need some of them to be gone completely. I have checked the Nunit documentation and googled this question and have yet to find the answer. I do not want to use additional third party tools. Can anyone help with this question?

Comment: This needs way more information. It's very unclear on what you are trying to do. You have Test A and B. You mean that sometimes you only want to run test B but not A?

Comment: Arran its one question How do I delete tests in Nunit. Its Clear.

Comment: No it's not. Delete tests? Well delete the code. Delete them how? Keep the code but not run them? When do you want to run them?

Comment: I want to delete them in the Nunit console.

Comment: That isn't possible because it simply isn't what the console is there to do. If you want the tests gone, either remove the code or place an `[Ignore]` over them.

Answer (score 0):

Your test probably looks something like this...

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests()
{
    [Test]
    public TestYouWantToDelete()
    {
        \\ You Test Code
    }
}
```

Remove

```
[Test]
public TestYouWantToDelete()
{
    \\ You Test Code
}
```

You could also comment it out and it wouldn't be picked up by the testrunner.

Also you could change the Assert to `Assert.Ignore();` if you might want to get it working again later.

Comment: Matt I am using a Script from Visual Studio I am not using any of the above.I loaded a csproj file. Where do i edit this information from? Do I have to change the code in the VS project and then copy paste it back over to this vm?

Answer (score 0):

Simply comment the `[Test]` attribute. Something like the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestsFixture()
{
    //[Test]
    public TestYouWantToDelete()
    {
        \\ You Test Code
    }
}
```

without `[Test]` attribute test code doesn't have any value. It will not simply run